# Trying to parse logs into AWS Athena using regex

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am very new to AWS Athena and regex, We are storing logs in S3 bucket and trying to use athena for querying puposes. 
Log example :

```
2018-03-13T14:05:40:624-0400  ID:414d512044414c444552323120202020eed8905aa3af1020                                                 |<Large String>
```

I am using the following command to store `date`, `time` `id` and `log` in the table -

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS monkey_banana_audit_logs (
  Date STRING,
  Time STRING,
  ID STRING,
  RAWMESSAGE STRING
  ) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
  WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "input.regex" = "^\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])* ^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d) (?<=ID:).*?(?=\s) [^|]*$",
  "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s"
  ) LOCATION 's3://monkey-business-dev/banana/tree/peel-log/2018-03-13/';
```

above Query is running fine but when I am trying to preview first 100 I am getting following error -

```
HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Number of matching groups doesn't match the number of columns
```

I am pretty sure there's something wrong that I am doing in my regex, I am working on it but posting this question here for a nudge in a right direction. 
I have already consulted the related posts but couldn't find something that would help me resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

`^(\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))T(([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d):([0-5]?\d)):\d{3}\-\d{4}.*(?<=ID:)(.*?)(?=\s) \|([^|]*)$`

Explanation: https://regex101.com/r/lfZmRI/1
Substitution will likely be: `$1 $4 $8 $9`

for your query you likely want to escape the backslash which gives you:

```
"input.regex" = "^(\\d{4}\\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))T(([01]?\\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\\d):([0-5]?\\d)):\\d{3}\\-\\d{4}.*(?<=ID:)(.*?)(?=\\s) \\|([^|]*)$"
```

Comment: Thanks, with help of my colleague I came up with "input.regex" = "^([0-9/-]+)T([0-9\\-:]+)[\\s]*ID:([0-9a-f]+)\\s*\\|(.+)"

Comment: That is clearly simpler to read, the original expression you posted performs a bunch of validation, lookarounds etc (for example, the first digit of month cannot be 3), and I tried to stay with that style.

Comment: totally understand, the new one is something that my colleague helped me with, let me try the one in your answer and upvote.

Comment: I think all the special characters should be doubly escaped

Comment: added escapes for backslashes